# SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am working on the Spring boot rest API with JWT Token to authenticate the requests. I have made multiple entries of Admin in DB and passing name as username, password as password in Basic Auth, but ends up getting SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() as null.

```
@PostMapping("/admins/login")
    public ResponseEntity<Admin> getLoggedInAdminDetailsHandler(Authentication auth) {
        Admin admin = adminDao.findByEmail(auth.getName())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new BadCredentialsException("Invalid Username or password"));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(admin, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
```

with Configuration as :

```
package com.olivestays.config;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain springSecurityConfiguration(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/staywell/customers/register").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/staywell/admins/register").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/staywell/hotels/register").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/staywell/customers/login").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/staywell/admins/login").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/staywell/hotels/login").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/staywell/rooms/add").hasRole("HOTEL")
        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/staywell/customers/update").hasRole("CUSTOMER")
        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/staywell/customers/getToBeDeletedAccounts").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterAfter(new JwtTokenGeneratorFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(new JwtTokenValidatorFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .formLogin()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();

        return http.build();

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {

        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    }

}
```

I have made multiple entries in DB for Admin, and when I am passing Username and Password in Basic Auth, it is showing 401 Unauthorized.

Admin request:

```
package com.olivestays.model;



import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty.Access;
import com.olivestays.enums.Role;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EnumType;
import jakarta.persistence.Enumerated;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Email;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Admin {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
    private Integer adminId;

    @NotNull @NotEmpty @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotNull @NotEmpty @NotBlank
    @Column(unique = true) @Email
    private String email;

    @NotNull @NotEmpty @NotBlank
    private String mobile;

    @NotNull @NotEmpty @NotBlank
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String password;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;
    
}
```

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: You do know that spring and multiple security sources do not recommend handing out jwts to browsers. Thats why there is no such thing as JWTfilters in spring security. Its an active choice to not have those type of filters. So please dont do that.